# Successfully logged in user keeps getting redirected to AccessDeniedPath using ASP.NET MVC CookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I added the [Authorize] attribute to the Home controller.

When a user logs in here is the code that runs:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = AuthManager.AuthenticateUser(model.Email, model.Password);

        if (user != null && user.Authenticated)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            IList<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email)
            };

            // Add role claims
            foreach (RoleResource role in user.Roles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name));
            }

            principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));

            AuthenticationProperties authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = model.RememberMe,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)
            };

            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("MyAppCookieMiddleware", principal, authProperties);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

I see that 2 cookies are created which is correct.

When I try to access a page from the Home Controller I get pushed to the Forbidden page that I have setup in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "MyAppCookieMiddleware",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Auth/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Comment: When you debug, does your code reach to `SignInAsync` method call?

Comment: @Win Yes, which creates the cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the line from

```
principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
```

to

```
principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
```

Comment: thank you so much! I actually ended up removing this and never realized it was what started messing things up. I can't remember what the default value was but it was some random string so I just got rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [Soham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45241242/1447862), you may want to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194482(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you use the constructor

```
ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
```

the value of the property `AuthenticationType` is `null`. The returned value of the property `IsAuthenticated` is "true if the AuthenticationType property is not null or an empty string." as you can read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated(v=vs.110).aspx)

Using the constructor

```
ClaimsIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, string authenticationType)
```

with a not null nor empty value for `authenticationType` will result in the `isAuthenticated` property returning `True`.

Comment: I can't put more than 2 links. You can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx) the available constructors and which properties they initialize.